# mailto is not opening windows native mail application in google chrome. It works properly from file explorer and other applications

Tags: windows, google-chrome, email, windows-11, windows-store-app

I am trying to redirect the mailto protocol from Google Chrome to the native Windows 11 mail application. The request keeps getting ignored; the mailto protocol does not redirect anything from (inside) Google Chrome.

If I change the handler in chrome to a website (Gmail.com) it works fine. But, when I remove the websites from chrome://settings/handlers hoping it will open Windows 11 native mail application, Google Chrome does not open the Windows 11 native mail application.

When I try the protocol mailto:test in other programs (Edge, file explorer…) it works properly and redirects me to the native Windows 11 mail application.
[image]
After Further investigations chrome does not open any windows store application for example: Microsoft store. I think it is something in the settings but I can't find it.
For example when I click [Get in the store app](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/shazam/9WZDNCRFJ0QQ?hl=en-us&gl=us) in this website.
Microsoft store application does not open.
https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/shazam/9WZDNCRFJ0QQ?hl=en-us&gl=us
[image]

Comment: With the handler in chrome removed, and the microsoft default set to the Mail app, what *does* happen when you try to open a mailto: link? Try using the longer url format in chrome like `mailto://test` too

Comment: DId not work.
Nothing happens!